# System call from Simulink possible?

Tags: matlab, system-calls, simulink

Is it possible to do a system call from [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink)? I haven't found it in documentation, but maybe there is a workaround. Or, it can be as easy as an function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an [Embedded MATLAB Function Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f6-6010.html) to run a MATLAB function from Simulink. Within this function you can make a call to the [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) function to execute an operating system command.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the answer I needed. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe this is possible through [S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bsd99w_-1.html). Unfortunately, you must drop down to C or C++ and deal with a very clunky interface to the model.  It's been a very long time since I've done work with an S-Function, so I'm afraid I can't help much beyond pointing out their existence.