# System call from Simulink with external hardware (Raspberry PI)

Tags: matlab, terminal, raspberry-pi, system-calls, simulink

I want to make a system call out of a Matlab Simulink model running on external hardware. 
In my case I want to switch the original Raspberry Pi Touch Display (7") off and an.

I tried using a Matlab function with a Matlab "system" command but it just doesn't have any affect on the display *(the system calls itself works with the terminal)*.

```
function display_backlight(old_status)
coder.extrinsic('system')

if old_status == 1
    system('echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power')
else 
    system('echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power')
end    
end
```

Any ideas how to make this work or do I need to use another block like mentioned here [System call from Simulink possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875981/system-call-from-simulink-possible) (Link in the answer doesn't work)

Or do I even have to write this in C and integrate this to Simulink?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution as it won't work directly from a matlab simulink block:

1. Add a "Matlab System" Block
2. Add an .m source file which runs .c/.h code.
3. Add a .c/.h file which runs the system command from c.

> ```
> #include <display_backlight_on.h>
>
> char command[50];        
>
> void display_backlight_on_command(boolean_T turn_on)
> {  
>     if (turn_on == 1)
>     {
>         strcpy( command, "echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power" );
>         system(command);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB `system` function is not codegen capable. So if you use `system` within a MATLAB function block, it will not generate code and so there won't be any effect.

You should create a new block if you want something as mentioned in the question.